# In my mobile application should I hard code the IP address or a domain name?

Tags: domains, ip-address, amazon-aws

I am building a social networking mobile application and currently deployed the backend on AWS.

I am wondering if it is a good idea to use the IP address in the mobile application or a domain name?

What if I wish to migrate the backend to some new cloud?

Harding coding the IP address will tie me up with AWS. isn't it?

What is your experience and take on this matter?

Comment: Hardcoding IP addresses is almost always a bad idea, especially since it's so easy to get DNS these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A domain name is owned by you.   You can take it with you when you move hosting.

The IP address is owned by your hosting company.   Hosting companies sometimes force IP address changes during internal switches.

Use the domain name if you don't want to be tied to your host.